# Why has my animation SVG animation stopped changing color?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, colors

I have some SVG animation on my website. A rectangle gets bigger and smaller, rapidly changing to a random color, while the words "Buy our crap" jump out of it.

For some reason, it stopped changing color. I can't remember changing or deleting anything. Why did it stop? What can I do to fix it?

```js
function rand(max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1));
}

function init() {
  let refreshRate = Math.random() *1000 + 50; // 10 times per second
  setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("RectElement").setAttribute("fill","rgb("+rand(255)+", "+rand(255)+", "+rand(255)+")");},refreshRate);
}

window.document.onload = init;
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="8cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 800 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <desc>Example anim01 - demonstrate animation elements</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="900" height="400"
        fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="2" />
  <!-- The following illustrates the use of the 'animate' element
        to animate a rectangles x, y, and width attributes so that
        the rectangle grows to ultimately fill the viewport. -->
  <rect id="RectElement" x="300" y="100" width="300" height="100"
        fill="rgb(0,255,0)"  >
    <animate attributeName="fill" begin="0" dur="1.3"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="x" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="300" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="100" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="width" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="300" to="800" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="height" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="100" to="300" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    
    
  </rect>
  <!-- Set up a new user coordinate system so that
        the text string's origin is at (0,0), allowing
        rotation and scale relative to the new origin -->
  <g transform="translate(100,100)" >
    <!-- The following illustrates the use of the 'set', 'animateMotion',
         'animate' and 'animateTransform' elements. The 'text' element
         below starts off hidden (i.e., invisible). At 3 seconds, it:
           * becomes visible
           * continuously moves diagonally across the viewport
           * changes color from blue to dark red
           * rotates from -30 to zero degrees
           * scales by a factor of three. -->
    <text id="TextElement" x="0" y="0"
          font-family="Verdana" font-size="35.27" visibility="hidden"  >
      Buy our crap!
      <set attributeName="visibility" to="visible"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <animateMotion path="M 0 0 L 100 100"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
           type="rotate" from="-30" to="0"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
           type="scale" from="0.5" to="2" additive="sum"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The rectangle is not changing color. I'm pretty new to this, so please be patient and suggest anything that you think could improve this question in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `window.document.onload`.
Change `window.document.onload = init;` to `window.onload = init;`.

[GlobalEventHandlers.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

[Window: load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)